# jquery chart plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

[screenshot http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/8514/chartz.jpg](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/8514/chartz.jpg)

hi , i know there is a lot of chart,pie chart open source available in jquery ,

but can u tell me , what is the name of the below screen shot chart plugin ,

am looking free open source link for the below chart ,

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's a jQuery chart plugin? Looks more like a mockup done in MS Paint to me ;)

But seriously, are you sure?

Comment: btw, 30% + 80% = 110% :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need: [jQuery UI Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)

By the way, you can do this without jQuery:

```
<div class="progess" style="width: 300px; background: silver">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 60%; background: blue"><!-- --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my Database i have fields like YES,NO , Assume if the YES is 8 means my bar goes to 80% green  color and 20% red color,

Answer (score 0):

Why not making it by yourself. It can be made using a nested `div` with a `length` style that matched the value. I have something like that in my old projects, with only css.